# Python List Comprehension (psutil)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, psutil

I have used psutil to get some information about processes. I will use the code in a loop. Is it possible to use list comprehension in the following code (for faster execution)?

Simplified code:

```
import psutil

list1 = []
for p in psutil.process_iter():
    with p.oneshot():
        list1.append([p.name(), p.pid])

Python 3.8
```

Comment: `[[p.name(), p.pid] for p in psutil.process_iter(["name", "pid"])]`

Comment: @Olvin Roght, I have tried it but it did not reduced the execution time (measured by using ````time()````).

Comment: Why do you think that list comprehension is faster than regular loop?

Comment: @Olvin Roght, I am new to programming but using list comprehension sometimes improves performance when used instead of regular loop. Not always. But it does not improved performance in this situation. It looks like performance mostly depends on internal mechanism of psutil.

Comment: You can try `[p.info for p in psutil.process_iter(["name", "pid"])]` or `[list(p.info.values()) for p in psutil.process_iter(["name", "pid"])]` if you need exactly same output.

Comment: @Olvin Roght, I have already tried it. It gives very similar performace relative to the code in the question, but it is faster than your first suggestion.

Comment: That's all I have, further boost you could possibly achieve working with OS api directly without third-party modules.